# Which answer should be accepted in tradition?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What factors should be considered to accept an answer: Time, completeness or what?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/what-factors-should-be-considered-to-accept-an-answer-time-completeness-or-wha)

Sometimes asked a question will possibly receive more than one answers, all of them are on topic and correct. In these cases is there any law to decide which one should be the final answer? 
The one earliest? The one with the most upvotes? Or the one with the most detail?

Comment: See this previous question: [What factors should be considered to accept an answer: Time, completeness or what?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3656/856)

Comment: It's helpful,thanks.

Comment: The one you like best, that helped you the most? It is, after all, up to you...(modulo correct-ness).

Comment: Only you can answer this question. And then you have to answer it again.

Answer (score 1):

How about the answer which best answers the question for you.

Comment: Yes, the best answer, of course, should be accepted. However, a question arose:does the best answer always exists? I think, generally, since the "superior to" relation is not necessary to be a linear order, or even a partial order. So there possibly no 'optimum answer' or even 'optimal answer'. Hence how to accept an answer in general seems a problem involves, I think, decision theory...

Comment: @Popopo isn't that a bit metaphysical, I mean that is like saying, do we really know anything.

Comment: Okay, but even this, sometimes it seems a bit difficult without a certain algorithm...